# Reduced chi square and degrees of freedom

Tags: chi-squared-test, model, degrees-of-freedom

I have a theoretical model to test against some data (grey line in figure). I perform 20 measurements of my data, with 10 points per measurement (red points spread over the x-axis). I want to compute the reduced chi square value for themedian value of my data against the model.

Not sure how I should accomplish this, can anyone help me? In particular I have difficulty understanding what are my degrees of freedom...

thanks!

[image: model (grey line) vs data (red points)]

Comment: please  show sample of your data in table format. Also mark whichone is X axis and Y axis in your graph.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "the median value of my data against the model."  Regardless, the answer will depend on how you fit the model and how many parameters were used in the fit.  Please supply this information.